# Converting application/hal+json to pojo

Tags: android, json, spring, rest, hal

I am pretty new to the Java landscape. I am trying to build a REST service using Spring Data REST and its Android client. At present I am trying to test (JUnit) the service.

I am getting the following response in Postman when I call the service to get a list of users (http://localhost:8080/..../api/users/)

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": [{
      "firstName" : "Maharaj",
      "lastName" : "NaamChakrawarti",
      "email" : "maharaj@mast.in.naam",
      "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/.../api/users/2"
       }
      }
    },{
      "firstName" : "Ji",
      "lastName" : "NaamChakrawartiDas",
      "email" : "G@Naam.masti",
      "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/.../api/users/3"
       }
      }
   }]
   },
 "_links" : {
   "self" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:8080/com.feiswrox.webserviceRS/api/users"
    },
    .
    .
   },
   "page" : {
     "size" : 20,
     .
     .
   }
  }
```

I tried to use following code to parse this response -

```
private static HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    String plainCredentials = "G@Naam.masti:ShreeRam1974";
    String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encode(plainCredentials.getBytes()));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return headers;
}
@Test
// @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void listAllUsersHal() {
    System.out.println("\nTesting listAllUsersHal API-----------");
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(getHeaders());

    Collection<Resource<User>> userList = null;

    ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<User>>> responseResource = restTemplate.exchange(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/users/", HttpMethod.GET,
            request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<User>>>() {}, Collections.emptyMap());

    if (responseResource.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        System.out.println(responseResource.getBody().toString());
        Resources<Resource<User>> userResource = responseResource.getBody();
        userList = userResource.getContent();
        for(Resource<User> userRsrc : userList){
            System.out.println(userRsrc.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting some value in userList variable but code execution skips for loop.
With the following code

```
    ResponseEntity<String> responseString = restTemplate.exchange(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/users/", HttpMethod.GET,
            request, String.class);
```

I get a string that is same as given above i.e.

```
{ "_embedded":{....
```

But I have no idea how to parse it to the list of users.

I used similar code to get convert single user from json and it worked.
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

```
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(getHeaders());
    ResponseEntity<Resource<User>> response = restTemplate.exchange(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/users/2", HttpMethod.GET,
            request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<User>>() {});

    User user = null;

    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        Resource<User> userResource = response.getBody();
        user = userResource.getContent();
    }
```

Am I making any mistake in type-casting the following code?

```
 Collection<Resource<User>> userList = null;

ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<User>>> responseResource = restTemplate.exchange(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/users/", HttpMethod.GET,
        request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<User>>>() {}, Collections.emptyMap());
```

Please help me to construct the list of users from json returned by REST service.

May i use same code in andriod application too?

Comment: If the `for` loop doesn't execute at all, that means `userList` is empty. You need to figure out why.

Comment: That is my question. What needs to be corrected in the code.

Comment: I suggest using a debugger or adding SOP calls to help you figure that out.

Comment: You should edit your original question so that you can format the code.

Comment: Ok will do so. Thank you.